# concept of "There tends to be a lot of"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I cannot place any meaning of the "tend" from the dictionary in the following sentence for having an acceptable concept:

> There **tends** to be a lot of obsidian flakes and chips in the hearth
>   ashes, but no chimney.

Comment: [Oxford English dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tend): "Regularly or frequently behave in a particular way or have a certain characteristic."

Comment: @PeterShor thanks. But it speaks from behavior. How is it reasonable for the mentioned sentence?

Comment: For the second part of the definition: "or have a certain characteristic", behavior doesn't have to be involved. What it means is that you usually see [wherever they're talking about] obsidian flakes and chips, and hearth ashes, but no chimney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is complicated by the use of the word "there", as a "dummy subject" indicating the existence of something.

See [Article about *Dummy Subject* **"there"**](https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-dummy-there.php)

In this case the verb meaning existence isn't just the simple "is", but the more complicated, "*tends* to be". "Tend" has meaning #1 in [MacMillan on-line dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tend)

> to usually do a particular thing

So the sentence builds up this way:

1) "A lot of obsidian flakes and chips are in the hearth ashes."

2) "A lot of obsidian flakes and chips *tend to be* in the hearth ashes." ( ... *Usually* are in the ashes);

and restating the sentence with the dummy subject "there", it becomes:

3) "*There tends to be* a lot of obsidian flakes ..."

Answer (score 1):

Phraseologically, though probably not a perfect substitute, the closest thing to the phrase **there tends to be** would be the phrase **there is a tendency that there are** where the word [tendency](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tendency) means *an inclination towards a particular characteristic or type of behaviour*. For example, if I have a tendency to argue about trivial or unimportant matters, it means that I tend to argue or I am given to arguing with people about trivial or unimportant matters. So, try to read your sentence like that and see if you can now better understand what it says:

> **There is a tendency that there are** a lot of obsidian flakes and chips in the hearth ashes, but no chimney.